# Is "[verbing] you a [noun] as [adjective] as you are" grammatically sound?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is "[verbing] you a [noun] as [adjective] as you" grammatically sound?

ie, *"Wishing you a day as lovely as you."*

I think it is, but the first part of the sentence "Wishing you a day" feels off.

Does changing the end to "...as you are" fix it?

Comment: If you consider sentence fragments not to be excluded per se from the 'grammatically sound' category, it's grammatical. Stylistically, the 'are' version sounds slightly better to my ears. Register-wise, it might be OK on a Valentine card.

Comment: Funny you should mention cards - my wife is a card illustrator and came up with the phrase for a recent piece; she was then told by someone that the sentence doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it does work, but am struggling to explain why it's not wrong (other than "it just isn't, ok!?"). Is there any specific thing I could point to there?

Comment: "Running you a hat as triangular as you." Yeah, I guess it's grammatical...

Comment: There are different requirements for different genres. And different authorities wielding the rod – but no overall grammar czar. In school, one may be marked down for not using 'proper sentences' in an essay. A scientific paper may be edited to remove a chatty style. A newspaper headline might be edited to be more punchy though less acceptable to the English teacher (spelling and punctuation as well as grammar). For sellers of cards, the only judges are the customers and the censor boards.

Comment: to (grammar) caesar what is (grammar) caesar's, I suppose :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here , "Wishing you a day as lovely as you" looks like a short way of saying
"[I am] wishing you a day [which is] as lovely as you [are]"

If we are okay with leaving out the first two parts "[I am]" & "[which is]", then we might also be okay with leaving out the last part "[are]".

It may not be great literature as such, but it will look fine in Valentine cards, provided the recipients are not grammar Nazis.

Comment: Reading it out "expanded" removes all the apparent weirdness, yes. Thanks that helps a lot! :)

Comment: @Heroes182 , glad to know that it was helpful !!